# "Unable to initialize 'OrderIntent'. Please make sure that your intent definition file is valid" error when creating an instant of custom intent

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode10, ios12, sirishortcuts

I have an `Intents.intentdeinition` file with a custom intent defined as `OrderIntent`.

[image]

When I try to instantiate this intent and set its parameter like this:

```
#import "TransactionCart+Intents.h"
#import "OrderItemIntent.h"

@implementation TransactionCart (Intents)

- (nonnull INIntent *)getCartIntent;
{
    ItemObject *item = self.itemManager.selectedItem;
    OrderItemIntent *intent = [[OrderItemIntent alloc] init];
    intent.quantity = item.quantity;
    intent.name = item.name;
    return intent;
}
@end
```

I get a run time console message on `OrderItemIntent *intent = [[OrderItemIntent alloc]init];` with this message:

`Unable to initialize 'OrderItemIntent'. Please make sure that your intent definition file is valid.`

The app continues to run however `getCartIntent` returns nil

I've tried recreating the intent definition file multiple times with various changes but still I can't get this to work.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem. Finally I find the reason.It is because I define the
`Intents.intentdeinition` file not in the main project, but in a pod library.As in a pod library you should add the code in your `podspec` file `s.resource = 'LCHomeModule/Classes/Intents.intentdefinition'`

Answer (score 0):

Change the category dropdown to "Order" or "Start". It's unfortunately a beta (as of beta 3) bug as mentioned here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103656